# Detect what file change with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have this gulpfile:

```
  var gulp = require('gulp'),
      concat = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

  gulp.task('minifyJS', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/*.js'])
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('min'));
  });

  gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['src/*.js'], ['minifyJS']);
  });
```

I want to know what file trigger the watcher and his absolute path.

For example: if my project is placed in */myCode* and I change the file *src/main.js*, I want to see ***/myCode/src/main.js*** inside **minifyJS** task. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `gulp-ng-annotate` and `gulp-changed`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'); // just as an example
var SRC = 'src/*.js';
var DEST = 'src/';

//Function to get the path from the file name
function createPath(file) {
    var stringArray = file.split('/');
    var path = '';
    var name = stringArray[1].split('.');
    stringArray = name[0].split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
    if (stringArray.length>1) {stringArray.pop()};
    return {folder: stringArray[0], name: name[0]}
}


gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src(SRC)
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        // ngAnnotate will only get the files that
        // changed since the last time it was run
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            var createdPath = createPath(path);
            path.dirname = createdPath.folder;
            path.basename: createdPath.name,
            path.prefix: "",
            path.suffix: "",
            path.extname: ".min.js"
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I want.

I need to change the destiny of the minified file depending on what file has change. For example: if I change *src/main.js* I will placed the minified file in *min/main.min.js*, but if I change *src/userView.js* I want to placed it in *min/user/userView.min.js*

Comment: You mean: 
`src/main.js` => `src/main/main.js` and `src/userView.js` => `min/user/userView.min.js` ?

Comment: I have just updated the code - it now use a generic function to create the correct path. Let me know if it suits your need. Cheers.

Comment: The problem here is that in the rename function *path* is an object that has a dirname key with value ***"."***. I need a way to translate ***./main,js*** to ***src/main.js***

Comment: Ok, forget that, it was an error copying your snippet. Now it works fine, thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `gulp-changed` npm package.

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-changed
```

Try the below in gulp file, (I haven't tried)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
      concat = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
      changed = require('gulp-changed');

  gulp.task('minifyJS', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/*.js'])
      .pipe(changed('min'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('min'));
  });

  gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['src/*.js'], ['minifyJS']);
  });
```

see the documentation of this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed

Comment: I know how to use that plugin and it's not what I want. I want to store in a variable. That's because I need to change the destiny of the file depending on the file I want to minify. Thank you anyway for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Julien's answer this should be fairly close to what you want, or at least get you going in the right direction:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cached'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    path = require('path');

function fileName(file) {
  return file.dirname + path.sep + file.basename + file.extname;
}

gulp.task('minifyJS', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/*.js'])
    .pipe(cache('minifyJS'))
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      var nameOfChangedFile = fileName(file);
      if (nameOfChangedFile == './main.js') {
        file.basename = 'main.min'
      }
      if (nameOfChangedFile == './userView.js') {
        file.basename = 'user/userView.min'
      }
      console.log(nameOfChangedFile + ' -> ' + fileName(file));
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('min'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['src/*.js'], ['minifyJS']);
});
```

This uses `gulp-cached` to keep an in-memory cache of all the files in your `src/` folder that have passed through the stream. Only files that have changed since the last invocation of minifyJS are passed down to the `gulp-rename` plugin.

The `gulp-rename` plugin itself is then used to alter the destination path of the changed files.

Note: the cache is empty on first run, since no files have passed through the `gulp-cached` plugin yet. This means that the first time you change a file **all** files in `src/` will be written to the destination folder. On subsequent changes only the changed files will be written.

Comment: Like you said, you get me in the rigth direction. I get the file name now, but I don't get the root; cuase I need both I'll continue my search for an answer. Thank you so much

Comment: If by 'root' you mean the absolute path of the changed files then don't do that. You shouldn't rely on absolute paths in your gulpfile. What if you move the project around? What if somebody else tries to build the project in a different location? Your tasks won't work in those cases. (If you really must, you can use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) to prepend the project location to `nameOfChangedFile`. Do so at your own risk.)

Comment: I really must know the absolute path rigth now. I have plans to change it in the future, but there's no other option right now.